# getting error no implicit conversion of sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

how to do below query in ruby sequel

```
table1.column1 = concat('a' + table2.column2 + 'b')
```

without 'a'

```
sequel.qualify(:table1, :column1) = concat(sequel.qualify(:table2, :column2) + 'b')
```

wokring properly.when adding 'a' also getting

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Sequel::SQL::StringExpression into String
>   /root/test/test.rb:13:in `+'

Answer (score 1):

```
{:table1__column1 => Sequel.join(['a', :table2__column2, 'b'])}
```